# getting the context in a class that implements Runnable

Tags: android, android-context, google-geocoder

I have an app in android that in a different thread from the UI(which implements Runnable)

I receive some data(GPS data in the form of latitude and longitude) and from this data I

wanna find out the right address by passing it to a Geocoder.....after that the address returned by  Geocoder I store it in a database:

Here is how I do these things:

```
public class Client implemets Runnable{


public void run()
{

Geocoder myLocation=new Geocoder(getApllicationContext,Locale.getDefault());



}

}
```

but I get error here:

```
Geocoder myLocation=new Geocoder(getApplicationContext,Locale.getDefault());
```

Runnable doesn't know who `getApplicationContext` is.....I tried with "this" instead but the same story.....

Now which is the right context to pass in to the Geocoder constructor????

Here is how the Geocoder constructor looks like:

```
Geocoder myLocation =new Geocoder(context,locale);
```

---

In my activity I do this:

```
public class Server2 extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {


ClientThread_special client = new ClientThread_special(db);//here is where I start thread


        new Thread(client).start();
}


}
```

---

```
public class ClientThread_special implements Runnable {



 public ClientThread_special(DBAdapter db){

     this.db=db;
    }


 public void run() 

{

Geocoder myLocation=new Geocoder(getApllicationContext,Locale.getDefault());


}


}
```

How should I modify the constructor

```
public ClientThread_special(DBAdapter db){

     this.db=db;

    }
```

in order to have in my Runnable the context of Server2?

Comment: Why are you using a Thread? Google recommends against such things: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: @Haphazard that link is dead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess your class `ClientThreadSpecial` is a separate class (not an inner class)? If so, why don't you pass the context from your calling Activity?

If it is an inner-class, it's even easier. Assuming your `ClientThreadSpecial`-class is an inner class of the `MyActivity`-class (which extends Activity), you can use something like this:

```
Geocoder myLocation=new Geocoder(MyActivity.this,Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: It's not an inner class...and that was exactly what I did...only it took a little time till I figured it out how to do it:)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `this` because `this` refers to a Runnable. Since the Runnable is defined within MyActivity (replace with your Activity / Service name), you can refer to `MyActivity.this`.